# curl and grep(?) to grab specifc string - how?

Tags: scripting, curl

I need to do some testing using curl against our web farm. Each server has some default page with some verbiage on it like this:

```
"Welcome to webappsrv01"
"Welcome to webappsrv02"   and so forth.
```

How can I use curl and grep(?) to grab the "Welcome to webappsrv(?)" string so I can see it the output on the screen as I hit the webfarm?
I need to know what server I am hitting.

Answer (score 6):

Use:

`curl -s https://example.com | grep -o "This doma.."`

Output:

`This domain`

Options:

- `-s` in `curl` is `silent mode` - it will not print progress
- `-o` in `grep` is `only matching` - only matching string will be printed
- `This doma` is pattern and two dots `..` means any character can be there so in your case it will be two digit numbers

Answer (score 2):

Not quite sure what you are asking, but as far as i can see you can use something like this

`$ curl <url> | grep -Po 'Welcome to webappsrv\d+'`

`-P` - PCRE regex, we use this for our `\d` which matches digit

`-o` - only matching word, not whole line

`+` in regex - match 1 or more times digit

Comment: Why did i get downote?

Comment: Tryna - This is good. I am indeed trying to catch the following two letters/digits after the host name (webappsrv01/02) etc. I made a mistake though. Some of the older servers in our lab have text like this:  "webapp 1" or "webapp 2".

IS it possible to skip a space and the grab then grab the number? Can you show me that please?

I did Upvote but I don't have enough reptuation credits for it show up.

Comment: Tryna - The second example didn't work for me. I got the following error:
-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('
These examples are still very useful and appreciated.

Comment: Matej - Your example worked great as well and it simpler for this specific task.
I did UPvote as well. Thank you,

Comment: @jogle900 `$ curl https://example.com | grep -Po '(Welcome to websrvapp01\d+)|(webapp\s\d+)'` will match "Welcome to websrvapp01" aswell as "webapp 1" and also "webapp 02"